# FireStore Data insert (Android Studio 3.6.1)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create new document in my DB in FireStore and insert a comment from my app, When I tried to debug My code in case of comment insert, I found 
 that onSuccess method is skipped, in every case when toAdd(String, this is the comment) isn't empty The 
 code runs onFailure Method, and I can't understand why. Here is my code:

```
    public void insertComment(View v) {

    toAdd = comment.getText().toString();

    if (!toAdd.isEmpty()) {
        //TODO : CHECK THIS SOLUTION (onSuccess not working)

        String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        Map<String, Object> comment = new HashMap<>();

        comment.put(COMMENT, toAdd);

        db.collection("Users").document(currentUser+" Comments").set(comment)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        counter++;
                        ListItem listItem = new ListItem(counter, toAdd);
                        listItems.add(listItem);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Comment saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    else {
        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Empty Comment!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the message you get from onFailure?

Comment: Your code should log the full exception so you can see what the error is.  `Log.e("TAG", "error", e)`

Comment: @AlexMamo "PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions."

Answer (score 0):

Solve it via Database -> Rules ->

Change allow read, write: if false; to true;